# Sugested way of working - Jenkins promotions or artifactory releases will deploy a war

Tags: deployment, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, continuous-deployment

We have a jenkins Job that package a WAR snapshot on every commit on SVN. 
We also use the Release plugin that generate a versioned WAR on artifactory.

```
example:web:1.1-SNAPSHOT >> 1.1
```

We want include the deployment task on the jenkins work flow. On different project we also work with the promote plugin.

We are not sure which is the better approach for work with the automated deployment task, based on the number of future problems that we could found.

The first solution planned is :

- Use the release plugin for generate a release stagging.
- Use the promotion plugin for authorize the automated deployment.
- This promotion launch a different job that download the last available WAR file from artifactory and deploy it.

We have discused if we can do it on the same "promotion action" or found a different solution.

Which solution is the most common for those cases? How we can restrict the accidental deployment of unauthorized versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't deploy the latest version, since you'll unintentionally deploy the wrong version, sooner or later.  Use [parameterized builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) to deploy a particular version. The deploy-to-artifactory job sets the parameter and uses the [parameterized trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to kick off all deploy-to-machine jobs.

You may want to parameterize all jobs in the pipeline after the deploy-to-artifactory job. I think there are other plugins that put the parameter into an entire pipeline, but I can't see them at the moment. There is a wide range of plugins that you can leverage in this workflow to suit your needs, such as the [BuildResultTrigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BuildResultTrigger+Plugin) plugin and the [Build Flow](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) plugin. And [matrix builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+matrix+project) are great for deploying to a range of machines, OSes, etc.

Comment: I have understood, your suggestion is doing it "manually" (setting the version manually)?

Comment: You can set the version any way you like. If you use maven, there are a couple of buildnumber plugins that are good to use, and they work well with the release plugin. Your numbering system doesn't seem to be a problem, the only concern is making sure that the artifact you think is version 1.1.1-release (or whatever) really is that version.

Comment: But we use the release to (artifact plugin)[https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plugin+-+Release+Management]. How we can launch a "deploy" task using this?

Comment: When you release to or promote in Artifactory, kick off another job (or use the BuildResultTrigger plugin to have anothe rjob kick itself off). That job deploys the artifact from artifactory to your CI/SIT/UAT environment, whatever's appropriate for you.

Comment: Thanks, I will check your solution.